# google maps fitBounds not working with ajax function - only seems to work with one marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a strange issue with fitBounds not working after an ajax call. On the initial page load, fitBounds works fine, and it centers 5 markers. However, after I click on one of the dropdown filters or the pagination (which triggers an ajax function to update the markers, it doesn't want to load, even though it appears to be trying to center the map based on where the markers should be. The filters are definitely working because I am also outputting a list of all maker locations beside the map.

I have also noticed, that if I adjust my query to only show 1 marker at a time, fitBounds tends to work better, although not all the time. It seems as though something in the "for loop" may be throwing something off. But I still don't have 100% success rate with only showing 1 marker. I just seems to work a bit better for the most part.

Regardless of how many markers I output with the ajax function, eventually, after clicking on the filters multiple times, it's like the map lags out. Sometimes it will show a marker, but the map behind it won't be right. And sometimes that map will start to get more and more distorted each time each time the filters are triggered. Another strange thing is that once I trigger the ajax function for new marker, if I hover over the zoom bar on the map, it automatically slides all the way to the bottom and can't be moved. And if I try to move the map by clicking and dragging, the whole thing turns solid gray.

Below is the first function that loads the markers once the page loads. It works fine and so does fitBounds at this point.

```
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-30, -209.6),
          zoom: 3,
          maxZoom: 4,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        // create the map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

        // array to hold the markers
        var markers = [];

        //  Create a new viewpoint bound
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();

        // Loop through array and add markers to map
        for( i = 0; i < jqueryarray.length; i++ ) {

            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(jqueryarray[i]['lat'], jqueryarray[i]['long']);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                icon: mapIcon, // just assume this has been set
                title: jqueryarray[i]['title']
            });

            //  increase bounds and fit to map
            bounds.extend (position);
            map.fitBounds (bounds);

            markers.push(marker);
        } // end of the for loop
```

And here is the other function that is called by ajax once the dropdown menu filters are trigged. Again, it seems to have trouble if more than one marker needs to be added to the map. The functions works perfectly without using fitBounds, though, so there is definitely an issue with the way I am using fitBounds.

```
// this function adds new map markers after a select menu change
        function addNewMarkers(json, count) {
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
                markers[i].setMap(null);
            }

            // reset the markers array
            markers = [];

            //  Create a new viewpoint bound. Do I need this again?
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
            //bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(null);

            // Loop through our array and add markers to map  
            for( i = 0; i < json.length; i++ ) {

                var myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(json[i].lat, json[i].long);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myPosition,
                    map: map,
                    icon: mapIcon,  // assume this has been set
                    title: json[i].title
                });

                //  increase bounds and fit to map
                bounds.extend (myPosition);
                map.fitBounds (bounds);

                markers.push(marker);
            } // end of for loop
        } // end of addNewMarkers function
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `map.fitBounds(bounds)` in each iteration of your loop.

Move this call *after* the loop instead of calling it each time. You need all of the points added to the bounds before calling `fitBounds()`.

Also, there is a large chunk of code duplicated between your two blocks of code. You should move this into a common function that you can call from both places.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. That was, indeed, the problem. I should have noticed that, but this is the first time I've ever worked with google maps.